# Display blank token values of file

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a group of tokens and its values in a file . I am writing a script where I am passing the tokens "only" and it will echo me the tokens and its values.
Now , I also want it should notify me the tokens which are not present in the file and which are having blank values.

greptokens.sh

```
    egrep -ve -R "FLAG|API|SERVER|MQ|USER|INSTANCE" | nawk -F  '[][]'  '{print $1,$2}' $HOME/host.tokens
```

host.tokens

```
    FLAG=YES
    API=NEW
    SERVER=SOA
    MQ=
    USER=DBO
    INSTANCE=SOA1
```

Output:

```
   $HOME/host.tokens:FLAG=YES
   $HOME/host.tokens:API=NEW
   $HOME/host.tokens:SERVER=SOA
   $HOME/host.tokens:MQ=
   $HOME/host.tokens:USER=DBO
   $HOME/host.tokens:INSTANCE=SOA1
```

In-case I add new token in host.tokens and donot update the script

new host.tokens

```
    FLAG=YES
    API=NEW
    SERVER=SOA
    MQ=
    USER=DBO
    INSTANCE=SOA1
    SERVER2=
```

Now my output should be

```
    FLAG=YES
    API=NEW
    SERVER=SOA
    USER=DBO
    INSTANCE=SOA1
   Blank values : MQ
   NOT AVAILABLE TOKENS : SERVER2
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Try adding a sample file or two and the desired output

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate. I updated the question

Comment: You can do the whole thing as a single awk script.  A first step would be to move your awk script to a file rather than trying to do a one-liner.  Then it will be easier to harness the full power of awk.

Comment: Thanks John.. but I didn't get that point of moving it in file

Comment: Your `egrep` command is nonsense: because you're using the `-e` option, the pattern is taken as `-R` and then you should see an error like `FLAG|API|SERVER|MQ|USER|INSTANCE: No such file or directory`. Which files are you trying to examine with the awk part? Is it only "host.tokens"?

Comment: yup.only host.tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* you want something like this: if

```
$ cat host.tokens
FLAG=YES
API=NEW
SERVER_FOO=SOA
MQ=
USER=DBO
INSTANCE=SOA1
```

then

```
  awk -F'=' -v tokenstr='FLAG API SERVER MQ USER INSTANCE' '
      BEGIN {
          n = split(tokenstr, ary, / /)           # ary is an indexed array
          for (i=1; i<=n; i++) tokens[ary[i]] = 1 # tokens is an associative array
      }
      {value[$1] = $2}
      END {
          for (token in tokens) {
              if (token in value) {
                  if (value[token]) 
                      print token " => " value[token]
                  else 
                      print token " => [blank]"
                  delete value[token]
              }
              else
                  print token " => [missing]"
          }
          for (token in value) 
              print "[extra] " token " => " value[token]
      }
  ' host.tokens
```

```
FLAG => YES
API => NEW
SERVER => [missing]
MQ => [blank]
USER => DBO
INSTANCE => SOA1
[extra] SERVER_FOO => SOA
```

Comment: Hi Glenn ,  I ran this and now I am getting  awk -F:  not found.

Comment: Did you try with `nawk`? What OS are you on?

Comment: yup.I am getting the same result. I am using unix OS

Comment: uname -a gives me AIX

Comment: maybe you need to leave a space after -F, I don't have access to AIX

Answer (score 1):

One idea that would work, although maybe not the most compact, would be to follow your "matches" command with a second grep|awk command that each look for NON-MATCHES of the same token list and outputs a formatted string of the literal "NOT AVAILABLE TOKENS : <first 'word' of line, i.e. the outlying token value>"

And just output the second command to the same target as the first (stdout, file, etc.)

Sorry don't have my awk hat on to give an example, but this functionally seems to achieve the desired result.